# Scraping JSON data from a URL that requires a login

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am testing this code.

```
#This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
POST-LOGIN-URL = 'https://my.freecycle.org/login'

#This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
REQUEST-URL = 'https://my.freecycle.org/home/posts'


payload = {
    'username': 'my_UN',
    'pass': 'my_pswd'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POST-LOGIN-URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(REQUEST-URL)
    print(r.text)   #or whatever else you want to do with the request data!
```

I found that code from the link below.

https://pybit.es/requests-session.html

The script is pretty straightforward.  I entered my actual credentials and got a 401 response (unauthorized).  This is telling me that I'm not authorized to access the URL using the credentials that I entered, but I know for a fact the credentials work fine when I log into the URL's main login page.  Am I missing something simple, or is this not designed to work given the setup I described above?

Comment: can you show HTML login code line in POST-LOGIN_URL link?

Comment: I just updated my original post.

Comment: <div class="auth-body" method="post" action="Action you have to mention">
......Your code 
</div>

Comment: Sorry, banoth, but I'm not following you. Can you post the exact code that you are suggesting I try?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the 'payload' variable does not have all of the right components. While on the outside to the user, the form only requires a username and password, those are not the only values apart of the POST request made after the form is submitted. Let's take a closer look into the login form of https://my.freecycle.org/login.

For your program to successfully, you need to include all of the inputs within the form. You have the username and password fields accounted for, but you are missing the hidden field known as 'referer' with the value of "". It should work when this is added. Generally, Hidden fields serve to submit information that the user does not input. So by changing the payload to look like:

```
payload = {
'username': 'my_UN',
'pass': 'my_pswd',
'referer': ''
}
```

You should be able to successfully login.

Comment: This didn't work.  I don't see why I would need 'referer'.  All I need is the username and password.  I'm sure of that.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution.

```
import requests 
import json
import base64

REQUEST_URL = 'your_JSON_URL'
login = 'FN.LN@your_email.com'
password = 'your_PW'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=(login, password))

json_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```